# Admob not archiving in Xcode but working on iphone 5 and simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, admob

For some reason Xcode is not archiving my project after adding AdMob to it.

I am currently using -objc and -all_load in the project because I am using Adobe Creative. Its working perfectly on an iPhone 5 and simulator but when I want to archive the project to upload it to the store it gave me duplicate symbols everywhere and it started after adding Admob.

```
Ld /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MemeHub-eiiudjckcbcbreabjhqaziopvmmq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MemeHub/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MemeHub.build/Release-iphoneos/MemeHub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MemeHub normal arm64
    cd /Users/Jose/memehub
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk -L/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MemeHub-eiiudjckcbcbreabjhqaziopvmmq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MemeHub/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MemeHub-eiiudjckcbcbreabjhqaziopvmmq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MemeHub/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Jose/memehub/MemeHub -F/Users/Jose/memehub/AdobeCreativeSDKFrameworks -F/Users/Jose/Documents/FacebookSDK -F/Users/Jose/memehub/MemeHub/Chartboost -F/Users/Jose/memehub -filelist /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MemeHub-eiiudjckcbcbreabjhqaziopvmmq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MemeHub/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MemeHub.build/Release-iphoneos/MemeHub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MemeHub.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework UIKit -framework StoreKit -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework MessageUI -framework Foundation -lz.1.2.5 -lsqlite3.0 -framework CoreData -framework Accelerate -framework MobileCoreServices -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation -lc++ -framework Social -framework Accounts -lsqlite3 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework FBSDKMessengerShareKit -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework Chartboost -framework AudioToolbox -framework Parse -framework ParseUI -framework AdobeCreativeSDKImage -framework Bolts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MemeHub-eiiudjckcbcbreabjhqaziopvmmq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MemeHub/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MemeHub.build/Release-iphoneos/MemeHub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MemeHub_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MemeHub-eiiudjckcbcbreabjhqaziopvmmq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MemeHub/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MemeHub.build/Release-iphoneos/MemeHub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MemeHub

>duplicate symbol l016 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdAppViewController.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerAdViewDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol l016 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdAppViewController.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdImage.o)
duplicate symbol l021 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
duplicate symbol l022 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
duplicate symbol l023 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
duplicate symbol l024 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
duplicate symbol l026 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMAdManager.o)
duplicate symbol l005 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMWebViewRenderedChecker.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdViewRenderedChecker.o)
duplicate symbol l006 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMWebViewRenderedChecker.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdViewRenderedChecker.o)
duplicate symbol l012 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSIReporter.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADPinger.o)
duplicate symbol l023 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSIConfiguration.o)
duplicate symbol l022 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l023 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l024 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l025 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l026 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l027 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l028 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l029 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l030 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l031 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l032 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l033 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
duplicate symbol l025 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTransparentOverlayPresenter.o)
duplicate symbol l026 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTransparentOverlayPresenter.o)
duplicate symbol l027 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTransparentOverlayPresenter.o)
duplicate symbol l028 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTransparentOverlayPresenter.o)
duplicate symbol l029 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTokenDispenser.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADTransparentOverlayPresenter.o)
duplicate symbol l016 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdAppViewController.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdNetworkJavaScriptAdViewDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol l017 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADRewardBasedVideoAd+Mediation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdNetworkJavaScriptAdViewDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol l018 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADRewardBasedVideoAd+Mediation.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMRAIDPicture.o)
duplicate symbol l021 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMRAIDResizeProperties.o)
duplicate symbol l022 in:
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttribution.o)
    /Users/Jose/memehub/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMRAIDResizeProperties.o)
ld: 33 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: remove the admob framework and the source headers from the project and make sure you have only one place where you have actually added the framework and the headers

Comment: you have added admob multiple times so such type of error occure. firstly remove admob from your project and then go to your project directory then remove admob folder manualy, and then try to install with proper procedure . https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start?hl=en .

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer, it looks its a bug on the Xcode version, I was using Xcode version 6.2 and the I just update to Xcode 6.4 and everything is compiling and archiving!

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the "-ObjC" linker flag from the "Other Linker Flags" section of build settings.  :)))